# Why does diff in Terminal say "No such file or directory" when the dir. exists?

Tags: gnome-terminal, diff, directory-structure

I am trying to use 'diff' in Terminal in a way that is very similar to half a year ago, but now it doesn't work. I get the "No such file or directory" error even though the directories obviously exist.

Here is a "screen shot" from Terminal. (I am sorry if it doesn't look good here, but I don't know how to make it look better.):

```
henrik@Henrik-L570:/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc$ diff --strip-trailing-cr -r -a --suppress-common-lines ”public_html-before” ”public_html-after” >outputfradiff.txt
diff: ”public_html-before”: No such file or directory
diff: ”public_html-after”: No such file or directory
henrik@Henrik-L570:/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc$ diff --strip-trailing-cr -r -a --suppress-common-lines ”public_html-before/” ”public_html-after/” >outputfradiff.txt
diff: ”public_html-before/”: No such file or directory
diff: ”public_html-after/”: No such file or directory
henrik@Henrik-L570:/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc$ dir
Dropbox                 Mine\ websteder    public_html-after
E-MAILS-TB\ 60\ Beta\ profile(tom)  OneDrive           public_html-before
E-MAILS-Thunderbird         outputfradiff.txt
henrik@Henrik-L570:/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc$ diff --strip-trailing-cr -r -a --suppress-common-lines ”/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc/public_html-before/” ”/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc/public_html-after/” >outputfradiff.txt
diff: ”/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc/public_html-before/”: No such file or directory
diff: ”/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc/public_html-after/”: No such file or directory
henrik@Henrik-L570:/mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/DataDoc$
```

Comment: Your command appears to use "smart quotes" `”public_html-before”` in place of regular ASCII quotes (did you copy+paste it from somewhere?)

Comment: You are 100% right! That solved the problem! I had copied from Libre Office...